# Extract Day of Week More Pythonically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, calendar

I have a df with fields year, month, day, formatted as integers. I have used the following to extract the day of the week.

How can I do this more pythonically?

```
### First Attempt - Succeeds
lst = []
for i in zip(df['day'], df['month'], df['year']):
    lst.append(calendar.weekday(i[2], i[1], i[0]))
df['weekday'] = lst

### Second Attempt -- Fails
df['weekday'] = df.apply(lambda x: calendar.weekday(x.year, x.month, x.day))

AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'year'", 'occurred at index cons_conf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `.to_datetime` and the `dt` accessor:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018, 2018], 'month': [12, 12, 12], 'day': [1, 2, 3]})

data['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(data[['year', 'month', 'day']]).dt.weekday

print(data)
```

Giving:

```
   year  month  day  weekday
0  2018     12    1        5
1  2018     12    2        6
2  2018     12    3        0
```

Note that weekday is zero-indexed.

Comment: No way! Didn't know that was there. Thanks!